# yii2 remove summary/count from ListView

Tags: php, listview, yii2

When I use `ListView` I it always does a count. For example says something like:

```
Showing 1-1 of 1 item.
```

My results/items are above. How can I remove this?

Current `ListView` code

```
<?=  ListView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'itemOptions' => ['class' => 'col-xs-6 col-sm-3'],
        'itemView' => '_index',]);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 25):

Found my answer used the following line:

```
'summary'=>'',
```

Comment: you can also change the layout: 'layout' => "{pager}\n{items}\n{pager}",

Comment: Is query `count()` still executed?

Answer (score 4):

Use **'summary'=>''** in your List view

Syntax:

```
<?= ListView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'itemOptions' => ['class' => 'item'],
        'itemView' => '_step',
    'summary'=>''

    ]) ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the 'summary' => '' as like below in html page:

```
<?php

echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $model,
    'summary' => "",
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        [
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'value' => function ($model) {
                return (!empty($model->name) && !empty($model->name) ) ? $model->name : 'NA';
            }
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'status',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function ($model) {
                return $model->getStatus();
            }
        ]
    ],
]);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `emptyText` too, to show your **custom messages**.

```
<?= ListView::widget([
  'dataProvider' => $dataProviderTodos,
  'pager' => [
  ],
  'options' => [
    'tag' => 'div',
    'id' => 'case-notes-wrapper',
    'class' => 'case-notes-wrapper'
  ],
  'layout' => "{items}\n{pager}",
  'itemView' => '',
  'emptyText' => '',
]); ?>
```

For more info, please [click](http://www.bmweb.co.in/how-to-change-default-no-result-found-text-according-to-you-need-in-yii-framework)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use:

```
'summary'=> false
```

I prefer `false` instead of empty string for better readability or in case you want to use a boolean expression (like: `$row_count > 0`).